# How to keep typing in cmd after opening emacs with bat file

Tags: batch-file, emacs, cmd

I have a bat file emacs.bat as shown:

```
@echo off
"C:\emacs-24.3\bin\emacs.exe" -q -l w:\handmade\misc\.emacs
```

After I run emacs.bat emacs opens, no problems. However cmd does not let me continue typing commands while emacs is open. I would like to be able to type commands into cmd with emacs open.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not just open Emacs with `runemacs.exe` and use CMD window separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add start "emacs" to the beginning of the command in emacs.bat:

```
start "emacs" "C:\emacs-24.3\bin\emacs.exe" -q -l w:\handmade\misc\.emacs
```

"emacs" is required for the text for the CMD title bar.

You can also make it work without opening a new window by adding /B after "emacs".

Comment: Technically, you can put anything for the title bar, including `""`, which gets displayed as nothing.